# JSON-LD always framing single object as array

Tags: php, arrays, json, json-ld, easyrdf

Is there a way to always force single objects to arrays with EasyRdf?

If there are multiple values as `rdf:type` I get an array like this one. Note the `@type` property is an array.

```
{
    "@context": {
        "ethon": "http://ethon.consensys.net/",
        "ethstats": "http://ethereum.ethstats.io/"
    },
    "@graph": [{
        "@id": "ethstats:Uncle_0x5cd50096dbb856a6d1befa6de8f9c20decb299f375154427d90761dc0b101109",
        "@type": ["ethon:Uncle", "ethon:Block"],
        "ethon:blockCreationTime": "2015-07-30T15:26:58.000Z",
        "ethon:blockHash": "0x5cd50096dbb856a6d1befa6de8f9c20decb299f375154427d90761dc0b101109",
        "ethon:number": "1"
    }]
}
```

But if there is only one `rdf:type` the `@type` property is not an array.

```
{
    "@context": {
        "ethon": "http://ethon.consensys.net/",
        "ethstats": "http://ethereum.ethstats.io/"
    },
    "@graph": [{
        "@id": "ethstats:Uncle_0x5cd50096dbb856a6d1befa6de8f9c20decb299f375154427d90761dc0b101109",
        "@type": "ethon:Uncle",
        "ethon:blockCreationTime": "2015-07-30T15:26:58.000Z",
        "ethon:blockHash": "0x5cd50096dbb856a6d1befa6de8f9c20decb299f375154427d90761dc0b101109",
        "ethon:number": "1"
    }]
}
```

When serializing the graph, I send to EasyRdf the options

```
'frame' => (object) [
    '@context' => (object) [
        'ethon' => 'http://ethon.consensys.net/',
        'ethstats' => 'http://ethereum.ethstats.io/',
],
```

Is there a way to send the `@set` option for the `rdf:type` / `@type` property?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! When [framing](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-framing/), pass additionally the `@context` option:

```
"@context": {
    ...
    "@type": {"@container": "@set"}
}
```

[See it in use.](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22dc11%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%22%2C%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Flibrary%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3ALibrary%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Flibrary%2Fthe-republic%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Flibrary%2Fthe-republic%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3ABook%22%2C%22dc11%3Acreator%22%3A%22Plato%22%2C%22dc11%3Atitle%22%3A%22The%20Republic%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Flibrary%2Fthe-republic%23introduction%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Flibrary%2Fthe-republic%23introduction%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3AChapter%22%2C%22dc11%3Adescription%22%3A%22An%20introductory%20chapter%20on%20The%20Republic.%22%2C%22dc11%3Atitle%22%3A%22The%20Introduction%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22dc11%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%22%2C%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%7B%22%40container%22%3A%22%40set%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3ALibrary%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3ABook%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22ex%3AChapter%22%7D%7D%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22dc11%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%22%2C%22ex%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22ex%3Acontains%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%7D)
(Click on *Flattened* and (back to) *Framed* tab if for some reason it doesn't show correctly on load.)